# Foundation 5.2.1 box-sizing scss Mixin not working

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation

Is it a bug that the mixin for box-sizing doesn’t return moz and webkit properties?

I have it in _global.scss as:

```
@mixin box-sizing($type:border-box) {
  box-sizing: $type;
}
```

So what I get is

```
/* line 299, ../sass/foundation/components/_global.scss */
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

The Compass mixin would be

```
@mixin box-sizing($type:border-box) {
  -webkit-box-sizing: $type;
  -moz-box-sizing: $type;
  box-sizing: $type;
}
```

For reference I am using Web Workbench plugin for visual studio. I can comment out the foundation mixin and include @import "compass"; in my Site.scss file to make it work but this is not a long-term solution.

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is something that can only be addressed by the maintainers of the library.